# Cannot delete all rows from my SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am populating an alertDialog from my database allowing a user to select a preset email message template. The populating seems to work but I cannot delete or edit it, only add to it. I wanted to delete all the rows and basically repopulate it from the beginning but I can seem to delete a single entry or all entries.

This is my deleting method in my DB Handler class:

```
public void deleteAppointment() {           
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLETEMP, null, null);         
}
```

This code I have used to try and delete all the rows but it dosent. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: is it not deleting anything?

Comment: @Woot4Moo No its not deleting or updating anything. It will just allow me to insert new items

Comment: Did you try catching exceptions, if any are raised? If not, please try that and post the logcat here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Drop table tablename  
--run rebuild scripts
```